# Problema na tradução de uma pergunta fechada

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Verifiquei que quando uma pergunta é fechada, a tradução não está correta:

> [**closed** as fora de escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42426/b%C3%A1sico-intermedi%C3%A1rio-e-avan%C3%A7ado-em-java)

Imagem:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]